# Backup a mysql database and download as a file

Tags: php, mysql

How to backup the mysql database and download it as a .sql file by using PHP Codes

Comment: I want to download the file using PHP script, from my Admin Panel

Comment: Following article will helps to backup and download mysql database as sql file or gz format.Also can be backup full database or specific tables. [http://faq.pctrickers.com/creating-mysql-database-backup-using-php/](http://faq.pctrickers.com/creating-mysql-database-backup-using-php/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple solution would be something like (first example):
http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

Naturally this will only make a Data dump of the table.

What you could do is use this code:

http://snipplr.com/view/173/mysql-dump/

What this code does is actually gets a description of the table (i.e its structure), creates all the tables and pushes data. pretty much like any other tool does.

Then its just a matter of saving it from string to a file (file_put_contents() for instance or something similar, depending on your preference and need)

Comment: You may, naturally, also just output the contents of the string and force download of it..

Comment: These uses deprecated `mysql_*` stuff. If there's something more up-to-date, I'd really like to know. I can't use phpMyAdmin.

Comment: This code does not include the keys (foreign, composite) you created except primary key.

Answer (score 3):

```
mysqldump -u username -p password database > file
```

Alternatively, phpMyAdmin can do this too with the Export tool.

Comment: Much faster than phpMyAdmin, but requires shell access. On the other hand, PMA will work just fine if you only have web access.

Comment: I want to download the file using PHP script, from my admin panel

Answer (score 1):

Use [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

Edit:

You can use  [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to execute this command

**mysqldump -u username -p password database > file**

This will generate a dump file,and then redirect user to this generated file.

Comment: I want to download the file using PHP script, from my Admin Panel

Answer (score 0):

Do you have phpmyadmin? If so you can export it from there by clicking "Export" at the top (on the selected table/db).

Comment: I want to download the file using PHP script, from my Admin Panel

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late but hope someone else will find this.

```
//php file - html code:
    require_once 'connect.php'; //holds database variables with connect details
    require_once 'Admin_DatabaseFiles_Backup.php'; //Include the admin logout script

<form action="" method="post" class="form form">
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="backup" value="1" />-->
    <div class="float_left w200">
        <p>
            <label class="title">Backup database</label>
            <span class="left">
              <input type="checkbox" name="db" value="1" checked="checked"/>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label class="title">Backup files</label>
            <span class="left">
                <input type="checkbox" name="files" value="1" checked="checked" />
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p class="float_left">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Backup" class="button" />
    </p>
</form>

//php file Admin_DatabaseFiles_Backup.php:
<?php


if ($_POST['submit']=="Backup"){

    if ($_POST['db'] == "1"){

        $directory = "DatabaseFileBackups/";
        $dateAndTime = "".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s');
        $fileName = "".$dbname.$dateAndTime.".sql";
        $backupFile = "mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password='$dbpass' --host=$dbhost $dbname > ".$directory.$fileName;

        exec($backupFile,$output);

        if($output == ''){ 
            echo = '<br />Failed To Backup Database!';
        }else{
            echo = '<br />Database Backup Was Successful!';
        }
    }

    if ($_POST['files'] == "1"){

            echo 'Seleceted files';

    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have phpMyAdmin you can do it at the Export menu.

If you look for a command-line tool take a look at [mysqldump](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/07/21/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/).