# Getting 0KB of size file while backup mysql database using mysql dump?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-2003

**Notes:** I tried all questions & answers related this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but not success. So please read my question thoroughly.

**Relative answer search**

**1.** [Getting 0KB of size file while backup mysql database using mysql dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920270/getting-0kb-of-size-file-while-backup-mysql-database-using-mysql-dump)

**2.** [Using PHP script: why mysqldump does not dump sql file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749853/using-php-script-why-mysqldump-does-not-dump-sql-file)

**3.** [Mysql PHP backup database using mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291453/mysql-php-backup-database-using-mysqldump)

***I want to Full database mysql (store procedure + table + trigger )*** i try to code then  not get any error but **0 kb** database Download

**`I connect Mysql CMD`** **Got Error like this**

> MYSqldump:Got error:2003 : can't connect to Mysql Server
>   '**`172.30.70.54`**' <10060> when trying to connect

**`Cmd Code Execute`**

```
mysqldump  --user=root --password= --host=172.30.70.54 dv-admin > db_backup5.sql
```

[image]

**Php Script**

```
<?php
    $dbhost = '172.30.70.54';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'mypass';
    $dbname='mydb';
    $toDay = date('d-m-Y');
    shell_exec("mysqldump --opt --routines -h$dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbpass --single-transaction $dbname  > db_backup.sql");
    system("mysqldump -opt -routines -h$dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbpass -single-transaction $dbname  > db_backup2.sql");
    ?>
```

Comment: and what's the error ? what's the real issue?

Comment: Try to run this dump command from cmd or cli first & check the file size

Comment: i try to  code then not get any error but 0 kb database Download

Comment: If you dump from a remote server read here more : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989724/how-to-mysqldump-remote-db-from-local-machine

Comment: I think you should give space between -h $dbhost ......

Comment: i also try `-h $dbhost` .. but not succes

Comment: Perhaps you should put the arguments **between single quotes**, like `system("mysqldump -opt -routines -h$dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbp...` to `system("mysqldump '-opt' '-routines' '-h$dbhost' '-u$dbuser' '-p$dbp'...`. If your username/password contains a space, then it is seen by the shell as two arguments.

Comment: i try your code @WillemVanOnsem  but again `0 KB` Download

Comment: Have you tried running `mysqldump` from terminal before creating this script? What's the use of this script anyway? Why not `.sh` from scratch? If you're trying to back MySQL up via browser, I'll just wish you good luck, it's an extremely bad idea.

Comment: `Can't connect` = you don't have access to connect to it remotely(either firewall is blocking you, or you need to add the settings to allow your IP), assuming your credentials are right. If your site is on cPanel, go to it and grant access to your IP.

Comment: i already set all grant access in database . my database store to cloud 1 &1 server

Comment: its not about granting all accesses, its about having an user that is allowed to your IP for example: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* to 'user'@'yourip' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` note the `to 'user'@'yourip'` in the command, **and for this to work your IP also needs to be allowed thru the server firewall**

Comment: i try @Prix code .but get other error like `grant' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file`

Comment: that is not a console command, its a mysql command, I suggest you either hire some one that understand what needs to be done or read more on how mysql, mysqldump, and mysqladmin CLI's work