# How can I use PHP to backup MySQL Database under Windows xampp?

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening,
I am currently working on a mysql backup system but I can't get it to run.

My current code:

```
exec ("C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe --routines -h $db_server -u $db_user -p $db_pass --single-transaction $db_name > C:\xampp\htdocs\test.sql");
```

I read the documentation on mysqldump and tried several ways, for example the above and also:

```
exec ("mysqldump --routines -h $db_server -u $db_user -p $db_pass --single-transaction $db_name > C:\xampp\htdocs\test.sql");
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) You are injecting raw input into shell 2) You aren't making any attempt to find out if the command executes successfully or to retrieve error messages if any

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by cannot run. It is it dump empty file or nothing at all happen. So I will write regarding on what I have understood. I also encounter same issues years back. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861240/4216992).

```
$filename = test.sql   

$command = sprintf("C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe --opt -h%s -u%s -p%s %s > C:\xampp\htdocs\%s",

$db_server,
$db_user,
$db_pass,
$db_name,
$filename
);
system($command);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this script
http://www.lecoindunet.com/sauvegarder-bdd-mysql-mysqldump-php-27

or this

[Using a .php file to generate a MySQL dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750531/using-a-php-file-to-generate-a-mysql-dump)